# Probability for Union of Events when one of the probabilities is 0.

Tags: probability

If, for example, $P(A \cup B)= P(B)$, does this automatically mean that $P(A)=0$ for all instances?

My understanding is that $P(A \cup B)= P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ wherein $P(A \cap B)= P(A) \cdot P(B)$. The only instance that $P(A \cup B)= P(B)$ is if $P(A)=0$ which leads to $P(A \cap B)=0$. Is there an exception to this or is there any particular situation wherein this might not be the case?

Comment: Suppose that $A=B$; then certainly $P(A\cup B)=P(B)$, and $P(A)$ clearly need not be $0$.

Comment: $ P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) $ is not a valid equality

Comment: What do you mean by not a valid one? I was referring to the formula

Comment: Quite.  $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B)$ is true if *and only if* $A$ and $B$ are independent events.  The correct general identity is instead $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\cdot \Pr(B\mid A)$.  Most of the time $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent and so you may not use your improperly used identity.

Comment: I see!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply consider $A=B=\Omega$. Then $P(A\cup B)=P(B)=P(A)=1$.

What goes wrong in your second paragraph is that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ is not true in general. It is only true when $A$ and $B$ are *[independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)#Definition)* events.

---

If $A$ and $B$ are *assumed* to be independent, then
$$
P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)=P(B)
$$
implies that $P(A)(1-P(B))=0$ which implies $P(A)=0$ or $P(B)=1$.

Comment: Does this apply even when talking about the probability itself and not the elements of the set?

Comment: @Fanoye:  I don't understand what you mean by "probability itself". But it does not make sense to talk about the probability of an element. One can only talk about the probability of an event.

Comment: It’s all clear now. Thanks!